# classes.dex file not found after I copied the android project from one machine to another

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I have copied two android projects from one machine to another and I am trying to run the same on the emulator, but every time I am getting the same error for both of the projects. Below is the error:

```
C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\Ashish\IFSTA-master\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexMerger\debug\5\classes.dex (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but all in vain.

Below is the screenshot of the logcat:

```
2018-12-24 12:13:49.952 2795-2795/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2018-12-24 12:13:49.951 2795-4588/? I/AudioController: internalShutdown
2018-12-24 12:13:49.954 2795-2795/? I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
2018-12-24 12:13:49.954 2795-2795/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
2018-12-24 12:13:49.954 2795-2839/? I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker 
cancelled
2018-12-24 12:13:54.535 1410-1410/? I/boot-pipe: done populating /dev/random
2018-12-24 12:13:54.963 2795-2795/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: 
#updateMicroDetector [detectionMode: [mDetectionMode: [1]]]
2018-12-24 12:13:54.963 2795-2795/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: 
#startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
2018-12-24 12:13:54.963 2795-2795/? I/AudioController: Using 
mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
2018-12-24 12:13:54.965 2795-2795/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2018-12-24 12:13:54.966 2795-2919/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting 
detection.
2018-12-24 12:13:54.966 2795-2868/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting 
com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@d29b41b
2018-12-24 12:13:54.968 1497-6204/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 
0xaa1031c0 tid=6204 ready to run
2018-12-24 12:13:54.972 1497-1608/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for 
AudioTrack size=131296
2018-12-24 12:13:54.973 1497-1608/? D/MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack 
(0xae5a0270, size=4194304)
    0: 0xae5a0280 | 0x00000000 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    1: 0xae5a02a0 | 0x000200E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    2: 0xadd75200 | 0x000401C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    3: 0xadd75400 | 0x000602A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    4: 0xae5a04b0 | 0x00080380 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    5: 0xae5a0640 | 0x000A0460 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    6: 0xadd75460 | 0x000C0540 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    7: 0xadd756b0 | 0x000E0620 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    8: 0xae5a07d0 | 0x00100700 | 0x000200E0 | A 
    9: 0xadd759a0 | 0x001207E0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   10: 0xadd75b10 | 0x001408C0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   11: 0xadd75d20 | 0x001609A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   12: 0xadd75e80 | 0x00180A80 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   13: 0xacd7c060 | 0x001A0B60 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   14: 0xacd7c1b0 | 0x001C0C40 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   15: 0xacd7c220 | 0x001E0D20 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   16: 0xacd7c530 | 0x00200E00 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   17: 0xacd7c730 | 0x00220EE0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   18: 0xacd7c860 | 0x00240FC0 | 0x000200E0 | A 
   19: 0xacd7c5a0 | 0x002610A0 | 0x000200E0 | A 

   2018-12-24 12:13:54.973 1497-1608/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() 
 initCheck failed -12; no control block?
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.973 2795-2868/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not 
 create record track, status: -12
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.976 2795-2868/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating 
 AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.976 2795-2868/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code 
 -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.977 2795-2868/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started 
 com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@d29b41b
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.980 2795-2868/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close 
 com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@d29b41b
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.982 2795-2919/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection 
 finished
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.982 2795-2919/? W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 
 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.984 2795-3044/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping    
 hotword detection.
 2018-12-24 12:13:54.984 2795-2919/? W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, 
 processing error from engine(4)
 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input 
 stream
    at 
 com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
    at 
 com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
    at 
 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at 
 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ag.run(Unknown 
 Source:4)
    at 
 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
    at 
 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bo.run(SourceFile:4)
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

Update SDK Manager and invalidate caches and restart android studio

Comment: did you check real device or emulator